# Installing GIT to windows

Tags: git

I am trying to download Git to my System (Win 10 64bit) via https://git-scm.com/download/win. But after downloading the setup and running, it shows an error message that the files are corrupt.

Following are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Please help me find a way so that I can download Git to my system.

Comment: Welcome to Windows 10 :-)

Comment: Might be more applicable to [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: probably ur setup is not for windows 10 , please download appropriate setup for windows 10

Comment: go direct to the Github release page https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases to get the installer, download it, and then check that your virus scanner isn't fouling it up, either by mistakenly claiming it is infected, not 'published', or failing to allow the installer to run. The one to go for is the https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.11.1.windows-prerelease.1 and select the one you need.